# Cols are not inline in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I just started learning bootstrap and I have an issue of `col`s not displaying inline even when they are in the same row.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sx-6">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>
                    Sit amet something else.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sx-6">
                <img src="http://www.irealb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/half-iphone-player.png" width="250px" alt="Iphone">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Expected Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjjM8.png

Actual Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCj8i.png

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ojhLm1vt/

I include Bootstrap the following manner:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `col-xs-*`, not `col-sx-*`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kw1wquem/)**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>
                    Sit amet something else.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img src="http://www.irealb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/half-iphone-player.png" width="250px" alt="Iphone">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```